# addition on std::atomic<double> not adding up to non-atomic counterpart

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, precision, atomic

I am trying to perform an addition on a double atomically in a loop using a compare and exchange scheme with this function:

```
namespace my
{
    template<typename value_type>
    value_type atomic_add(std::atomic<value_type>& operand, value_type value_to_add)
    {
        value_type old = operand.load(std::memory_order_consume);
        value_type desired = old + value_to_add;
        while (!operand.compare_exchange_weak(old, desired, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_consume))
            desired = old + value_to_add;

        return desired;
    }
}
```

This is used in my code like so:

```
[ size of containers = 62, scalar = 318.0, values in containers between 0.0 and 55.0, all values are of type double ]

for(size_t i = 0; i < container.size(); i++)
{
    my::atomic_add<double>(Q, container2[i] - std::pow(container3[i], 2) / scalar);
}
```

The output is `0.57784502195324539`.

However, replacing all my_atomic with the `+=` operator, and replace all `std::atomic<double>` with `double` gives `0.52something`, which is closer to what I was expecting.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! :) I think we will need a [mcve] to figure this one out.

Comment: Will provide, thank you!

Comment: Can't you use `std::atomic_fetch_add` ?

Comment: @Arunmu Unfortunately not; `std::atomic_fetch_add` only works for integral types. In this case I need floats.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed this issue so I am going to post an answer as a cautionary tale for other developers.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

namespace my
{
    template<typename value_type>
    value_type atomic_add(std::atomic<value_type>& operand, value_type value_to_add)
    {
        value_type old = operand.load(std::memory_order_consume);
        value_type desired = old + value_to_add;
        while (!operand.compare_exchange_weak(old, desired, std::memory_order_release, std::memory_order_consume))
            desired = old + value_to_add;

        return desired;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vector;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        double a;
        a = 2.0;
        vector.push_back(a);
    }

    std::atomic<double> d;

    for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
        my::atomic_add(d, vector[i]);

    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

The output of which is `202`. It appears that `d` is initialized to `2.0`. The moral of this story is to always make sure that your `std::atomic`s are initialized to a sane value.

Furthermore, other answers have pointed out that it is generally a bad idea to store `std::atomics`s in a vector as they are not `CopyAssignable` and `CopyConstructible`.

Comment: I would recommend you edit your question to contain the example. The real reason for your problem, then, is undefined behavior: as you noticed, [`std::atomic`'s default ctor does not initialize the data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic). `d` happens to be 2.0 because the value happens to already be in that stack location from the previous loop (`double a` held the same place). If you change your code to `a = 4.0`, you'll likely get `404` as a result. But that is just what your compiler happens to do; really, you're just seeing UB.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320008/whats-the-default-value-for-a-stdatomic (your post turns out to be a duplicate).

Comment: @mindriot I will amend accordingly; It does turn out to be a duplicate, however my first suspicion was that this was a fringe floating-point error. Looking back this was a naive assumption.