# No compiler warnings for uninitialized std::atomic<double>

Tags: c++, initialization, g++, clang++, stdatomic

Earlier today I stumbled over [addition on std::atomic<double> not adding up to non-atomic counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40882023), which turned out to be due to a `std::atomic<double>` being left uninitialized (see also [What's the default value for a std::atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320008)).  What caught my attention, though, was that my compiler did not warn me about the fact that the `std::atomic<double>` was uninitialized.  Consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
  std::atomic<double> d;
  double e;

  std::cout << d << " " << e << std::endl;
}
```

Neither clang 3.8 nor GCC 6.2 appear to be able to produce a warning for `d` being uninitialized. See [live at coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3949d1e3622f1a98): I used `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra`, but got no warning both with and without `-O2`. Of course a warning about `e` not being initialized is typically produced. <sub>(Interestingly, gcc does not actually produce any warning when `-O2` is enabled.)</sub>

Of course I cannot *expect* the compiler to warn me about these things; but this case left me wondering:

- Is there a particular reason why this situation is not (currently) detected/reported by the compilers in question?
- …or even (I would assume this to be unlikely): Is it impossible in general, for some reason, to detect/report the missing initialization in the specific case of `std::atomic<T>` where `T` has no default constructor?
- or, maybe, is there just another command-line switch I am missing which would make the compiler produce the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Why: Unfortunately we have no way of knowing. Perhaps nobody who contributes to gcc development bothered to do it yet or thought it was worth it.

Impossible to detect? Not technically, I suppose. But it would have to be a special case, otherwise you'd introduce loads of warnings for a not uncommon case of declaring vars of struct and class types with no explicitly defined default constructors without initializer lists or whatever.

Worth it to add a special case? Probably, but that's a matter of opinion, and convincing somebody to implement it in gcc.

Command line switches? Not really, although [`-Weffc++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099692/easy-way-find-uninitialized-member-variables) might get you something. I have not tried it. You could also try running it through valgrind, maybe that will report something. Also have not tried.

Comment: Thanks. I tried `-Weffc++`, unfortunately it makes no difference in this case.